# Update a MySQL record only when the old value of a filed does not match the new value using CASE Statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case-statement

I have a PHP function I am building that will be used to Mass "Complete" Project Tasks that belong to a particular Project.

If a Project has 50 Task records then my current solution would update all 50 records, setting the `status` column to `Completed` and the `date_modified` column to the current now DateTime.  This new  `date_modified` value would be incorrect too since only some of the Status's actually changed from their previous value!

I would like to build a SQL Query that would instead...

- Only UPDATE records that are not ALREADY set to `status` === `Completed`
- Same with the `date_modified` field, it should only update this DateTime for records actually being updated now!

Here is part of the SQL that I had took out of another query that did something completely different but it does have the correct table and field names and demonstrates how a `CASE Statement` might be the correct path.  I however do not know enough MySQL to be able to do such an advanced style query on my own and would appreciate all the help I can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Update the status and date from tasks where the status is not completed" pretty easily translates into:

`UPDATE tasks SET status = 'Completed', date_modified = NOW() WHERE status != 'Completed'`

(you could also set your `date_modified` column up in a way that automagically updates to the current timestamp with each update. Didn't find the docs-link, but search for "on update current_timestamp")

Comment: OMG, I was so caught up with my CASE statement on another query that I wasn't even thinking straight, I feel pretty silly now, thanks for pointing to the obvious!

Comment: no problem, people tend to think too complicated sometimes :)

Comment: In regards to your last update about auto-updating the modified date, the reason I didn't go that route is I have a Sort column and a Drag n Drop interface which then updates the sort order of all records which would result in that modified column being updated all the time when it shouldn't be, thanks for the suggestions though